# How to sort data of a file in python(windows)

Tags: python-3.x

We are trying to implement a file based student record program.We want to sort the file that contain the details of  the student according to the roll number which is at the first position of every line.

the file contains the following data:

```
1/rahul/cs
10/manish sharma/mba
5/jhon/ms
2/ram/bba
```

We want to sort the file's data according to the first field i.e. roll number.

Any help shall be great

Comment: What's your question? This is quite broad as is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate We want to sort the file according to the first field, the numeric values i.e. roll number(uid)

Comment: What code have you already got?

Comment: i have tried
   `sorteddata=list(sorted(f.readline()))`
but this dosent helped much

Answer (score 0):

You use `sorted`:

```
dataSorted = list(sorted(f.readlines()))
```

If you want to sort only the first element use:

```
dataSorted = list(sorted(f.readlines(), lambda line: line[:line.find('/')]))
```

`f` is the file-object.
Further information: `help(sorted)`

Comment: when we do the sorting with your code it only sort with the first digit.
this take 123 smaller then 2 as 1 is on the first place in 123 it does not compare the whole number